# How To Convert Arabic Number Ascii Code to String in ROR?

Tags: ruby, ascii, numbers

I want to convert my English Numbers Pager to an Arabic one, 
I had something like

```
<% @engnum = "0123456789" %>
<% @arabnum = "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩" %>

<%= (@pagenumber).to_s.gsub(/./) {|s| @arabnum[@engnum.index(s)]} %>
```

But this shows the ascii number not the actual number i need

Any idea how to show the actual string (Number) 
Remember that it's arabic numbers and `@arabnum[@engnum.index(s),1]` didn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a ruby question, you can leave out `<%` and `%>` out and this is pure ruby code.

Answer (score 4):

```
#encoding: utf-8
pagenumber = "512"
p pagenumber.tr("0123456789","٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩") 
#=>  "٥١٢"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
@pagenumber.to_s.gsub(/./) {|s| @arabnum[i=@engnum.index(s),i]}
```

For more information about this you should read http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000771